# So how to I reference the value of one cell as a series name using VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

this question is probably easy to solve but I cannot figure out how to do it and a quick web search didn't lead to anything. So here is my code:

```
Option Explicit

'Description: This macro is used to number plot all specimens into the stress-strain curve since this has become a task that
'has to be done very frequently
Sub PlotAllSpecimens_Tensile()
Dim ws As Worksheet, wb As Workbook
Dim xrng As Range, yrng As Range, namerng As Range
Dim CH As Chart, CHcond As Chart, CHdry As Chart
Dim Material As String, state As String, Temperatur As String, name As String
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, idry As Integer, icond As Integer, k As Integer
Dim ser As series
Dim startrow As Integer
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
idry = 1
icond = 1

For Each CH In wb.Charts
      If CH.name = "Stress-Strain curve cond" Then
            Set CHcond = CH
      ElseIf CH.name = "Stress-Strain curve dry" Then
            Set CHdry = CH
      End If
Next CH

If Not CHdry Is Nothing Then
      For Each ser In CHdry.SeriesCollection
            ser.Delete
      Next ser
End If
If Not CHcond Is Nothing Then
      For Each ser In CHcond.SeriesCollection
            ser.Delete
      Next ser
End If

For Each ws In wb.Worksheets


      If ws.name <> "Start" And ws.name <> "Auswertung" And ws.name <> "Zusammenfassung" Then
            i = 1
            For k = 1 To 15
                  If ws.Cells(k, 5 * i - 4) = "Material" Or ws.Cells(k, 5 * i - 4) = "Werkstoff" Then
                        Material = ws.Cells(k, 5 * i - 3).Value
                  ElseIf ws.Cells(k, 5 * i - 4) = "Temperatur" Then
                        Temperatur = ws.Cells(k, 5 * i - 3).Value
                  ElseIf ws.Cells(k, 5 * i - 4) = "Zustand" Then
                        state = ws.Cells(k, 5 * i - 3).Value
                  End If
            Next k

            While Not IsEmpty(ws.Cells(i * 5 - 4).Value)
                  name = Material & "_" & i & ", " & state & ", " & Temperatur
                  Set namerng = ws.Cells(1, 5 * i - 1).End(xlDown).Offset(-1, -1)
                  namerng.Value = name
                  startrow = ws.Cells(1, 5 * i - 1).End(xlDown).Row
                  Set xrng = Range(ws.Cells(startrow, 5 * i - 2), ws.Cells(startrow, 5 * i - 2).End(xlDown))
                  Set yrng = Range(ws.Cells(startrow, 5 * i - 1), ws.Cells(startrow, 5 * i - 1).End(xlDown))

                  If Not (CHdry Is Nothing) And state = "dry" Then
                        CHdry.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
                        CHdry.SeriesCollection(idry).XValues = xrng
                        CHdry.SeriesCollection(idry).Values = yrng
                        CHdry.SeriesCollection(idry).name = ??????????
                        CHdry.SeriesCollection(idry).Border.ColorIndex = 42 + ws.Index Mod 5
                        idry = idry + 1
                  End If
                  If Not (CHcond Is Nothing) And state = "conditioned" Then
                        CHcond.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
                        CHcond.SeriesCollection(icond).XValues = xrng
                        CHcond.SeriesCollection(icond).Values = yrng
                        CHcond.SeriesCollection(icond).Border.ColorIndex = 42 + ws.Index Mod 5
                        CHcond.SeriesCollection(icond).name = ???????
                        icond = icond + 1
                  End If

                  i = i + 1
            Wend
      End If
Next ws
End Sub
```

**?????** marks the issue. I want to name my series the value of the cell "namerng" so if i later change this cell the name in the plot will update. This can be done manually in excel by selecting a cell as the name range. If I use:

```
CHcond.SeriesCollection(icond).name = namerng.value
```

The results will be correct but do not change after I change the value of the namerng. **So how to I reference the value of one cell as a series name using VBA?**

Comment: I think you are saying that you need to tie this to a worksheet_change event where the target is the range of cells holding the series names? You appear to know how to assign a name via a variable to a series. Without inspecting the code fully, my immediate worry is that this is overkill to change just one thing so i would extract the naming part out into its own sub maybe so only this is triggered? I have entirely thought it through tbh.

Comment: QHarr is correct if you are wanting to update the name whenever you update the value of namerng, then a Worksheet_Change event is what you are looking for.

Comment: @QHarr well a worksheet_change event would certainly work but I solved it. One actually needs to type out the name of the cell using a .address and .name then setting it together like excel when you would do it manually. Pretty ugly but works.

Comment: And it should have read as "i haven't entirely thought it through".... Apologies.

Answer (score 1):

I got it it is:

```
CHcond.SeriesCollection(icond).name = "='" & ws.name & "'!" & namerng.Address
```

Not very elegant but it works.

Comment: Karma is nice.. I was looking for this answer today, found it, wanted to upvote, "You can't upvote your own post" xD Nice. Thank past me I guess!

Comment: Thank you. I struggled a moment with this one.